# bundle.js:10910 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im getting this error here:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" className="dropdown-toggle autodropdown">
                <NavLink
                  to="/"
                >
                  <div >
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={24} height={24} viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2} strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" className="feather feather-home"><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z" /><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22" /></svg>
                    <span>home</span>
                  </div>
                </NavLink>
              </a>
```

I'm new to React, How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think you need the `a` element when using `NavLink`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't know that, thank you so much, it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NavLink or `<a>` because NavLink also a `<a>` tag, so using NavLink inside  doesn't make sense here.